# Can I find all music files on computer with electron?

Tags: electron

I'm thinking about making music player for linux but i'm not sure if it's possible to find all music files and what should i use for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using node's [walk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk) package.

You'll want the user to select a folder where music is stored because it would take a lot of time to search through every directory on user's machine and find .mp3 files.

It is pretty well documented. It takes the path to the selected folder and loops through all files. Pretty straightforward.

something like this might work

```js
const walk = require('walk');
const files = []

const walker  = walk.walk("music/", { followLinks: false });

walker.on('file', function(root, fileStats, next) {
      // Add file to the list
      files.push(root + '/' + fileStats.name);
      next();
  });

walker.on('end', function() {
      console.log(files);
  });
```